# do-while to make a yes or no answer? java

Tags: java

My current objective is to make this line of code continue to run over again as long as the "yes" is the true, or if it is "no" then stop, or if it is invalid prompt the user to make a correct selection. I'm completely lost on what to do.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Temperature
    {
     public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number, a space and F to convert from degF to degC and C to convert to degC to degF");
        double deg = input.nextDouble();
        String letter = input.next().toUpperCase();
        char dg = letter.charAt(0);
        //String prompt;
       tempLoop:
        do{
            if( dg == 'C'){
                double cTemp= (deg-32)*5.0/9.0;
                System.out.printf("%f degC converted to degF is %.2f%n",deg, cTemp );;
            }
            else if(dg == 'F'){
                double fTemp = (deg*9/5) + 32;
                System.out.printf("%f degF converted to degC is %.2f%n",deg, fTemp );
                continue;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That character does not correspond to a valid unit of measure ");
                break;
            }
        }while(!(dg == 'C' || dg == 'F'));
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(yes/no)"); 
      }
     }
```

Comment: If you could do the __same__ thing in the inner loop, what is the confusion?

Comment: @devnull I'm not sure where to start

Comment: @devnull could you possibly ellaborate?

Comment: Try to search a bit, you'll find numerous examples of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I updated your code a bit. You are now able to Type 15F, 15C, ... (without whitespace) to convert. After this you will be asked if you want to continue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double deg = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out
                    .println("Enter a number and F to convert from degF to degC or C to convert to degC to degF");
            String text = input.next().toUpperCase();

            try {
                deg = Double.parseDouble(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (text.endsWith("C")) {
                double cTemp = (deg - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0;
                System.out.printf("%f degC converted to degF is %.2f%n", deg, cTemp);
                ;
            } else if (text.endsWith("F")) {
                double fTemp = (deg * 9 / 5) + 32;
                System.out.printf("%f degF converted to degC is %.2f%n", deg, fTemp);
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("That character does not correspond to a valid unit of measure ");
            }
            System.out.println("Type YES to continue");
        } while (input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
        input.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the USER input only one time so i m not sure why you are using `do-while` loop.Also if you are trying to iterate on the basis on YES\NO then add the inputs in the `do` loop and add one for input about YES/NO and add this check in while.

Use below code :

```
public class Temperature
 {
 public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    double deg;
    char dg;
    String con;

    do{
         System.out.println("Enter a number, a space and F to convert from degF to degC and C to convert to degC to degF and YES to continue");
        deg= input.nextDouble();
        String letter = input.next().toUpperCase();
        dg = letter.charAt(0);
        con = input.next();

        if( dg == 'C'){
            double cTemp= (deg-32)*5.0/9.0;
            System.out.printf("%f degC converted to degF is %.2f%n",deg, cTemp );;
        }
        else if(dg == 'F'){
            double fTemp = (deg*9/5) + 32;
            System.out.printf("%f degF converted to degC is %.2f%n",deg, fTemp );
            continue;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That character does not correspond to a valid unit of measure ");
            break;
        }
    }while(con.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
} }
```

Comment: I want to restart loop the user input to do it as long as it is prompted with  a yes

Comment: Updated the answer now u have to give input as 50 C YES to continue and 50 C (other than YES) to exit

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the loop to include the user-prompting code and change it so that it only happens again after the user types "yes".  Like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature
{
 public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    double deg;
    char dg;
    String prompt;
   tempLoop:
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a number, a space and F to convert from degF to degC and C to convert to degC to degF");
        deg = input.nextDouble();
        String letter = input.next().toUpperCase();
        dg = letter.charAt(0);
        if( dg == 'C'){
            double cTemp= (deg-32)*5.0/9.0;
            System.out.printf("%f degC converted to degF is %.2f%n",deg, cTemp );;
        }
        else if(dg == 'F'){
            double fTemp = (deg*9/5) + 32;
            System.out.printf("%f degF converted to degC is %.2f%n",deg, fTemp );
            continue;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That character does not correspond to a valid unit of measure ");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(yes/no)");
        prompt = input.next();
    }while(prompt.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")); 
  }
 }
```

Comment: how would I go about making yeah it drop the previous user input for new input ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to ask for the user's input BEFORE you start the loop again. This way, at the end of the loop, it asks the user if he/she wants to continue. If the answer is "yes", then the code will continue to loop. If the answer is "no", the program will exit the loop and move on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature
{
 public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number, a space and F to convert from degF to degC and C to convert to degC to degF");
    double deg = input.nextDouble();
    String letter = input.next().toUpperCase();
    char dg = letter.charAt(0);
    //String prompt;
   tempLoop:
    do{
        if( dg == 'C'){
            double cTemp= (deg-32)*5.0/9.0;
            System.out.printf("%f degC converted to degF is %.2f%n",deg, cTemp );;
        }
        else if(dg == 'F'){
            double fTemp = (deg*9/5) + 32;
            System.out.printf("%f degF converted to degC is %.2f%n",deg, fTemp );
            continue;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That character does not correspond to a valid unit of measure ");
            break;
        }

        System.out.print("Would you like to continue?(yes/no) ");
        String cont = input.nextLine();
    }while((!(dg == 'C' || dg == 'F')) && cont.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature
{

private static String reply;
 public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number, a space and F to convert from degF to degC and C to convert to degC to degF");
    double deg = input.nextDouble();
    String letter = input.next().toUpperCase();
    char dg = letter.charAt(0);
    //String prompt;
   tempLoop:
   do{ 
   do{
        if( dg == 'C'){
            double cTemp= (deg-32)*5.0/9.0;
            System.out.printf("%f degC converted to degF is %.2f%n",deg, cTemp );;
        }
        else if(dg == 'F'){
            double fTemp = (deg*9/5) + 32;
            System.out.printf("%f degF converted to degC is %.2f%n",deg, fTemp );
            continue;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That character does not correspond to a valid unit of measure ");
            break;
        }
    }while(!(dg == 'C' || dg == 'F'));
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(yes/no)"); 
    reply=input.next().toUpperCase();
   }while(reply.equals("YES"));
  }
 }
```